# Example of Using an S3 Class in a S4 Object

Tags: r, methods, r-s4

I want to include an RODBC connection as part of S4 object. It looks like RODBC is S3. For example:

```
setClass(
  Class="Node",
  representation=representation(
    nodeName = "character",
    connection = "RODBC"
  )                    
)
```

Throws `undefined slot classes`. It looks like I want to use `setOldClass`, but I am having trouble figuring out how to use it. Assuming I do want `setOldClass`, How would I use `setOldClass` so that I can include my RODBC connection as slot to my Node class?

Comment: Is it as simple as: `setOldCass("RODBC")` and then just exactly what I have above? If so I feel a bit sheepish ...

Comment: yes, `setOldClass("RODBC")` is all you need.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Although the documentation is quite involved for this function, if all you need to do include the class in a slot it is as simple as:

```
setOldClass("RODBC")

setClass(
  Class="Node",
  representation=representation(
    nodeName = "character",
    connection = "RODBC"
  )                    
)
```

This is also what you would use for reference classes.

Comment: It will not work when I use roxygen2 to document it. If I put `setOldClass("RODBC")` into a single file. When checking, it will be "the specification for S3 class “dist” in package seems equivalent to one from package ‘graph’: not turning on duplicate class definitions for this class."