# Make parallel clusters within a S4 class

Tags: multithreading, r, class, parallel-processing, r-s4

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [S4 Classes: Multiple types per slot](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13002200/s4-classes-multiple-types-per-slot)

I am trying to make my first R package.
I plan to create a S4 class "test" that contains data and some methods to process data.
In my case, the processing of data can be improved by multi-threading.
I have tested `parLapply()` and it increases performance.

The problem is that I do not want to call:

```
cl <- makeCluster(N)
parLapply(cl, x, FUN, ...)
stopCluster(cl)
```

in each method I want to make parallel. This is because it is not elegant and, I presume, the repeated creation (and destruction) of the teams of thread costs.

Therefore, I was thinking about (simply) having a `cluster` object within my class "test".
Then I could, for instance, make a "test" object "o" and call a method of "test" `setNumbrOfThreads(o) <- 4`.

However, I have trouble with the implementation. Since `?makeCluster()` states the return value is '''An object of class 'c("SOCKcluster", "cluster")''', I have tried :

```
setClass("test",
    representation(
        data = "list",
        nThreads = "numeric",
        cluster = c("SOCKcluster", "cluster") #This seems incorrect
    ),
    prototype(
        data = NULL,
        nThreads = 1,
        cluster = makeCluster(1) # "cluster = NULL" does not help
    )
)
```

R complained that `element 3 of the representation was not a single character string`
.
So I tried without more success: `cluster = "cluster"` or `cluster = "SOCKcluster"` (in representation).

My question is:

**How can I can I create an S4 class with a member object of class c("SOCKcluster", "cluster") ?**

Thank you,

Comment: @BrandonBertelsen Thank you, I will try that and update. I am having a hard time with R and OOP.

Comment: The solution to Brandon's question worked for me. This is a duplicate indeed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Brandon asked about putting different types of objects ('apple', 'orange') into a single slot; you're asking about using an S3 class in an S4 object. The notation `c("SOCKcluster", "cluster")` is S3's way of saying that `SOCKcluster` contains `cluster` as a parent class. This is a duplicate of [Example of Using an S3 Class in a S4 Object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9067492/example-of-using-an-s3-class-in-a-s4-object), **not** of [S4 Classes: Multiple types per slot](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13002200/s4-classes-multiple-types-per-slot), and with a twist -- you have a (short) S3 class hierarchy, not just a single S3 class. The solution is in the same spirit, though, with

```
setOldClass(c("SOCKcluster", "cluster"))
A = setClass("A", representation(cluster="SOCKcluster"))
```

and then

```
> library(parallel)
> a = A(cluster=makePSOCKcluster(2))
> a
An object of class "A"
Slot "cluster":
socket cluster with 2 nodes on host 'localhost'
```

Trying to put an MPI cluster (requires `snow` and `Rmpi`) into your class fails

```
> a = A(cluster=makeCluster(2, "MPI"))
    2 slaves are spawned successfully. 0 failed.
Error in validObject(.Object) : 
  invalid class "A" object: 1: invalid object for slot "cluster" in class "A": got class "spawnedMPIcluster", should be or extend class "SOCKcluster"
invalid class "A" object: 2: invalid object for slot "cluster" in class "A": got class "MPIcluster", should be or extend class "SOCKcluster"
invalid class "A" object: 3: invalid object for slot "cluster" in class "A": got class "cluster", should be or extend class "SOCKcluster"
```

Creating a class that supports `cluster` would require reading of `?setOldClass`.